# How do I include array from another PHP file

Tags: php, arrays

In the handle_signup.php page, I try to handle with the data which was sent from the sign up page. If the nickname blank has no value, then the error message is "Please enter your nickname". So, in the signup page, I try to include the $errorMsgs array from handle_signup.php page and show the msg below the nickname input. How can I get the array from the handle_signup.php page? Currently, I use include_once, but there is no message in the array after transferring to handle_signup.php. Could some one help this issue? Thank you.

**Handle the value from signup.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('./conn.php');
  $errorMsgs = array('nickname'=>'', 'email'=>'', 'password'=>'');


  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
      $errorMsgs['nickname'] = "Please enter your nickname";
      header("Location: ./signup.php");
    }
  };
?>
```

**Sign up page - signup.php**

```
<?php
  include_once 'handle_signup.php';
  var_dump($errorMsgs);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <title>Message Board - Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container_sign">
    <h1 class="title">Create Account</h1>
    <form class="sign" method="POST" action="./handle_signup.php">
      <div>
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" name="nickname">
      </div>
      <p class="warning__msg"></p>
      <div>
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
      </div> 
      <p class="warning__msg"></p>
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
      </div>
      <p class="warning__msg"></p>
      <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" name="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are redirecting from page X to page Y, meaning all variables will be lost. Store your error messages in a session to make them persistent and be able to some them on page Y

Comment: Thank you, DarkBee. The problem is solved!

Comment: No prob, glad you've got i solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DarkBee suggested, you can use `$_SESSION` for your error messages, or simply don't use `header("Location: ./signup.php")` but include all your PHP code in the same page.